# Installing Elasticsearch using composer

Tags: elasticsearch, composer-php

I am trying to install Elasticsearch using composer. I downloaded composer and it works properly when executing `composer -v` in the command line. I then created a file called composer.json and executed `composer install` in that file's directory. This is what I received afterwards:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing react/promise (v2.5.1): Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download react/promise from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/reactphp/promise/zipball/62785ae604c8d69725d693eb370e1d67e94c4053" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
failed to open stream: Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy
```

After searching online, I tried changing my PHP.ini ca-bundle certificate file path, but it's still not working. The PHP version I am using is 5.6.25 and it is on WAMP Server. How can I fix this error so Elasticsearch is installed?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with proxy setting as according to the logs you have `Cannot connect to HTTPS server through proxy`. There is an issue thread related to this [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5411). If you haven't already go through it, please do so.

One suggestion is to set proxy on windows at user level "HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy.yourdomain.com:port".

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch
```

https://github.com/matchish/laravel-scout-elasticsearch#search-amongst-multiple-models